# How to include resources in iphone static library?

Tags: ios, iphone, static, resources

I'd like to include files, data and images in a static library API so the users won't need to include them manually in their project.
I see that there isn't obvious way to do it but is there some hack or workaround to achieve this goal ?

Comment: Also see [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5709997/136569) for additional info:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use `xxd` with the `-i` command line parameter and use a wrapper function/method that feeds the data into a `NSData`

```
- (UIImage*)getMyImage
{
    return [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithBytes:file_ext 
                                                 length:file_ext_len]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So after referencing the frameworks programming guide, @codeflakes pointed out that dynamic frameworks aren't possible on iPhone OS. I found [this link](http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/iphone/iPhone_Framework_Support.20081202.html) which looks like it has a static lib that includes a few resources. I downloaded the PlausibleDatabase lib referenced there and did see a couple items in a Resources directory. I think the static lib has to build it's own pseudo-bundle structure to get at those things.

Comment: But I though you could not write your own Framework on the iPhone ?