# Add images, string file to static library in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, static, resources

I want to make a static library which basically displays some views and button. My client wants this to be distributed as a library to be used by other iPhone developers.

My doubts are

- Can we add images and other resources to the library .a file?
- How can we include localization to this static library?(localizable.strings??)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A library plus images and resources is exactly what a framework is for, not a static library. (Disclaimer: I'm a Mac programmer, not an iPhone programmer, so for all I know maybe frameworks are less common on iPhone.)

Comment: I know this is pretty old now, but custom frameworks are fully allowed by apple I have built some myself and apps have been accepted.

Answer (score 4):

This is correct, you CAN't include localitation files to your static library. This only one of many disadvantages you have to deal with when developing a static library.

To make your static library localized, add the Localizable.strings files you have created to your project, that includes your library and all works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Since Frameworks are not allowed on iOS, you have 2 likely choices:

1. Package a "Resources" folder alongside the static library. This contains your images, etc.  Provide documentation to the user of the library as to where the resources should go (presumably copied into the app's Resources folder).  Localization files would be imported into the project.
2. Base64 (or whatever) encode images, etc, and compile those as static data into the library code.  This is a little awkward, but it can be done.  You have to un-encode them when loading them for display (NSData etc). You could provide a resources class which stores the encoded objects and returns them in their un-encoded form.  One obvious drawback here is that your code could get pretty large -- make sure you only load the resources when actually needed and unload when done..

I don't believe you can embed (for later use) localization string files however.

Comment: this seems like the real answer. Frameworks may be the standard, but since they are not allowed in iOS this is a better solution. Option one allows the app developer to change the icons for the library. and option two allows the library developer to keep their own icons.

Comment: This is not the correct answer custom frameworks are fully allowed as long as they are done correctly. I have built some and my apps have been accepted by apple many a times.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify. When I say Framework, I mean it in the sense that Apple uses it, that is, a "versioned bundle". The app can refer to different versions of the code within one bundle. It implies dynamic linking, and most frameworks (os x) are linked dynamically at runtime, not statically. Also frameworks aren't something that show up in Xcode's targets for iOS. However, it's certainly possible to create a bundle, and package things in it that will be compiled in and/or added to your app bundle at _compile_ time.  However, it doesn't seem worth the extra work.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert images into binary data and add them to the library as a char[].
Then when the image is needed just use

```
[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:(void*)<CHAR_ARRAY_NAME> length:sizeof(<CHAR_ARRAY_NAME>) freeWhenDone:NO]];
```

This simple application will help you to convert images https://github.com/RomanN2/image-to-binary-data