# adding resources to static library in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, plist, static-libraries

I am going to create a Static Library, But I am facing problem while adding my images and plists to it.

Is there any way to do this ?
I have found some linke like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808673/how-to-include-resources-in-iphone-static-library) but it doesn't help me because not able to understand it.

Please help

Comment: @Shaggy Frog - Problem means in WHich section should I add those files "Copy Bundle resources" or "Copy files" or any other ?
also will they can be used as a normal way like [UIImage imageName "image1.png"]

Comment: A static library is an archive of object files, nothing else.  You can make your project copy bits and pieces around but it's not going to work well at all.  You need to use a framework for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can include non-traditional library resources like images or plists if you first create a [cocoapod](http://cocoapods.org/) for your library and use this in your .podspec:

`s.resources = 'LibraryName/**/*.{png,plist,xib,and,so,on}'`

The client project that uses your cocoapod will then include your resources.